# Adding response headers to laravel 401 api response

Tags: php, laravel

Am using laravel with android and whenever a 401 error is triggered in laravel i would like to attach to the 401 error a custom header

```
WWW-Authenticate: xBasic realm=32334
```

Whenever a 401 response is returned to android i get

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

So after aresearch i found out the problem is due to the fact that i need to add a header to the response given i laravel

So am using the default passport `oauth/token` route which routes are set in authservice provider like

```
 public function boot()
  {
     $this->registerPolicies();
     Route::group(['middleware'=>'appconnection'], function(){
         Passport::routes();
     });
  }
```

As from above ive added an appconnection middleware to passport routes now i want to handle the response to check if 401 is ever returned and add the custom header

so in my middleware am stuck at adding the header

```
class AppConnectionMiddleware
 {
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
       $returned = $next($request);
         //check if $returned has a 401 status response 
         //am stuck here

     }
 }
```

So how do i manipulate the response to include the custom response header

Comment: what version of laravel you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if ($response->status() == 401) {
         $response->header('WWW-Authenticate', 'xBasic realm=32334')
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: should this be $request->status() or $response->status()